# How to use uploaded files from .net core API in my angular application?

Tags: c#, angular, .net-core

I have trouble with display a image in my Angular app.
This is in my profile.ts and profile.html page

```js
 public createImgPath = (serverPath: string) => {
    return `http://localhost:63040/${serverPath}`;
}
```

```html
 <img class="img-responsive" src="{{createImgPath(userApi.user.imageUrl.folderName)}}" />
```

From the server I get filepath:

```cs
var folderName = Path.Combine( "userImages", fileName);
 return Ok(new { folderName });
```

When I try to display image in src I get the path but image is not display.

[image]

And I got error message:

[image]

Comment: Did you configured `userImages` folder for static file serving? [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1#code-try-4)

Comment: Yes, because userImages is in wwwroot folder I use:
 app.UseStaticFiles();

Comment: Is that image open's in the browser?

Comment: yes, but don't work when i try to load from angular app the same url

Answer (score 1):

It was very silly typo mistake. Instead "usersImages", in var folderName I used to use "userImages". I'm sorry for trouble to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're supposed to return the file as a blob. Because you cannot send your images as a JSON to angular. Well, at first, change your backend code to something like this:

```
var folderName = Path.Combine( "userImages", fileName);
return new FileStream(folderName , FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

and then change `[HttpGet]` to `[HttpPost]`

I don't know how to send your image file to the backend but I think you can fix your problem with these changes.